# Erro .gitmessage ao fazer commit

Tags: git

Estou começando a usar git agora e quando tento fazer `git commit` acontece o seguinte:

```
fatal: failed to expand user dir in: '~./gitmesage'
```

Já dei `git add .` e mesmo assim o erro se repete. Alguém sabe qual pode ser o problema?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o comando commit com uma mensagem? seria assim: `git commit -m "inicio do projeto"`. O parâmetro `-m` é para adicionar uma mensagem ao seu commit.

Comment: Sim, o erro é o mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Seu Git está configurado com um template de mensagem, mas esse arquivo de template não existe mais. O que você pode fazer é recriar esse arquivo com `touch ~/.gitmessage` ou simplesmente zerar essa configuração no seu arquivo `.gitconfig`.

```
[commit]
  template = ~/.gitmessage # remova essa linha
```